# Docker run - MySQL Springboot Connection refused

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker

i'm new to Docker and have been trying to Dockerize a simple springboot and MySQL project.

I have created an image for spring boot and also have a container for my springboot project and a separate container for MySQL.

When I attempt to log the container logs for the MySQL part it works with no errors.

**docker container logs mysql-standalone**

---

```
2021-12-20T18:27:56.109823Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-12-20T18:27:56.184989Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2021-12-20T18:27:56.375549Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-12-20T18:27:56.376015Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.27'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

But, when I try to log for the Springboot project I get an error

**docker container logs springboot-docker **

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
```

**My current containers**

[image: Docker ps -a]

When I attempt to run the project locally with an IDE it works perfectly, the endpoints work fine with no errors.

I'm not too sure where the problem lies, if anyone has some ideas please let me know.

---

**New Error**

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
```

**application.properties** (Database config)

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-standalone:3306/docker_demo?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Answer (score 1):

Update 01: Updated cmd, written here for code block

```
docker run --name mysql-standalone -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=docker-demo -e MYSQL_USER=demo -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:8.0.27
```

Short answer: you need to run the docker container with the port specified like so:

```
docker run -it -p 3306:3306 mysql
```

Then you should be able to connect :)
If you share your docker file or docker-compose, i will be happy to assist with the command.

Longer answer is that you need to bind the container port to your host machines network in order for non-dockerized services to be able to access the port on the container. This is very usefull when having to run multiple mysql containers on the same machine, then you just bind to a different host port and everything should be good to go :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, my Dockerfile looks like this

`
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre

ADD target/docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar springboot-mysql-docker.jar

EXPOSE 8089

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","springboot-mysql-docker.jar"]
`

Sorry for formatting

Comment: What command did you use to run the mysql container? Thats the command we need to tweak :-)

Comment: **MySQL**
docker run --name mysql-standalone -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=docker-demo -e MYSQL_USER=demo -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:8.0.27

**Springboot**
docker run -d --name springboot-docker --link mysql-standalone:mysql springboot-docker

Comment: I updated my original response with the updated command. If you start the container like that, it should work. Don't forget to bring down the current container.

Comment: I've pruned my local images and built them again, ran MySQL container using the command you gave but gives the same error. 

Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Comment: Alright, i am missing some information, so i have to make some assumptions. Another common misstep is to use localhost as host, try using 0.0.0.0 instead. Otherwise i will have to see your connection info in the spring boot to tell you something concrete :)

Comment: Did it work? :)

Comment: idk im clueless at the moment lol.

I repackaged my spring boot application, created an image etc and when i log the container info im getting a new error, i edited my original post, it's at the bottom along with my properties file for database config

Comment: I think i might know the issue, in my application.properties i have it configured to my root   mysql instead of the new instance i made named "demo". I'll try changing the datasource username and let you know

Comment: Couple of suggestions to try: change "mysql-standalone" to "0.0.0.0". I think container name only works as dns in docker-compose.
If that didnt work, change the password from password to secret. Newer versions of mysql might not allow password as the password (if i remember correctly)